# How to get type key name from object key in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

```
type transaction = {
    uid: string,
    paymentMode : string,
}
```

I want to get key name from type for e.g.

```
function getFieldName(input) {
  returns a string with key name
}

const tran : transaction = {}
getKeyName(tran.paymentMode) returns 'paymentMode'
```

I read many articles and tried some solutions, so I understand we will at least need to create object for that type which is fine.

I want to do this because key name of a type is required and I also want to keep auto-complete for key name when we type something like `obj.key` to avoid mistakes.

I know, I can create a separate object from type with constant key, value pair. I want to avoid this, because then we will need to change same thing at 2 places whenever there is a change in type, which can be missed.

Edit:

I was looking for exactly this - [nameof in c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof). @Aleksey L. told this in comments.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do. Your desired output needs matching input which you know beforehand, so I am finding it hard to think of a situation this would be used in. Your example `getKeyName(tran.paymentMode)` is equivalent to something like `getKeyName("hello")` - there is no way to tell where that string came from, whether it belongs to an object of a certain type, etc.

Comment: Do you want a function `getKeyName` that returns a key of an indexed type? es. `getKeyName(tran.paymentMode)` and after calling it `tran.paymentMode` type is exactly the `'paymentMode'` string?

Comment: Input and output are diff in this way:
I want type safety, example in the future if a field name changes, I will get a red line everywhere that field is used, if I use something `Transaction.uid` instead of a string directly.

I am writing an internal layer b/w database and models. we need strings for database calls but want to pass keyName in a way it can be auto-completed. e.g. `Transaction.uid`

Also I can then add this thing in Base class, so that we don't need to write 2 types for same thing.

Comment: yes @MircoBellagamba.
I don't really care about the value of object in this case. I just want key name as a string. without writing it myself as a string.

Comment: If I understand correctly you're looking for something like [nameof in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof). There's no such a thing in javascript/typescript

Comment: yes @AlekseyL. exactly what I was looking for. I was hoping to find a way to do this in js/ts also.

Comment: If you need to restrict some function's input to valid type key - just use `keyof` operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be the type of function signature that you want:

> Note that it meets your criteria of compatibility with IntelliSense auto-complete/suggest:
>
> [image]

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTgQwHYGcEGNgEsD2SoC8UA3gFBRQCuWAJgFxQrBxZIDmA3OVGAiALYQkwALI4aEBkxbsuAXy6kAZpSSZc+NhGAAxLBAA2NAHIJBUADwwoEAB7AhNFFBwAjAFYRMAGigBpG3tHZwBrCBAcJVgAPgAKHAYYXzCQBj8ASjSSbjhtSjh8FPlSUnQ8JihmZDR1PETEVAxsPEJsimp6KAB3VhocLoA6dDhwYBwBhr7+AFVpgEkAEVj0725eASFRcUkoAHJVEKR+pF3VhRKtXX0jU0FYqsbapF992l30jigAei+oACIOn9SJc9IYTGYIPcGjVms89utBMIxBJ3p8fv8EZtkRAgcDtKCbhCodUmhoXggUDQlKjvgAqbgURlM5kspkAPw5nNIAEE4GxKIjgC4oqBIHs-hSqX9dlAsM4jkKKSgsGwkAhXAZoGMeAhEIIHHBhZVwNBdilIrBoaS8LsBrEAEwAZgALABWdJQWlfUhAA)

```ts
type Transaction = {
  uid: string;
  paymentMode: string;
};

function getFieldName <T extends object, K extends keyof T>(o: T, key: K): K {
  return key;
}

const transaction: Transaction = {
  uid: window.crypto.randomUUID(),
  paymentMode: 'unknown',
};

getFieldName(transaction, 'uid'); // "uid"
getFieldName(transaction, 'paymentMode'); // "paymentMode"

getFieldName(transaction, 'asdf'); /*
                          ~~~~~~
Argument of type '"asdf"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof Transaction'.(2345) */
```

---

It is not possible to derive a string property name in JavaScript (or TypeScript) by passing a reference to the property value. JavaScript simply doesn't have this kind of meta-introspection capability at present.

It appears that your question is not just about type safety, but about DX/ergonomics. The above solution does require providing the property name, but the number of extra characters to type before getting the IntelliSense prompt is only 1 (2 if you consider whitespace):

```
// For: obj.prop:

// desired:
fn(obj.p_)
//   012^

// proposed:
fn(obj, 'p_')
//   01234^
// The closing quote is auto-inserted by IntelliSense, just like the closing parenthesis.
```